# Remove my Google account on other people's device

Tags: google-account

I once had to log in my Google account on my friend's phone and I forgot to delete my account on his phone. Is there any way for me to remotely delete my account on my friend's devices?

Answer (score 23):

Go to [Google's security manager page](https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity), find the phone you logged in on and click "deauthorize".

Comment: I was just too late to give the same answer you did.....

Comment: Thanks. it works. really appreciate it. Once again, thanks for helping me.

Comment: That link is (now) for apps, https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity is where one should go

Comment: The "Account access" and "Remove" button is not shown in https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity?pli=1 page.  Do anyone know why?

Comment: @EugineJoseph, you must click onto the device you wish to disconnect. Then a menu will come up with those items.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to "gracefully" disconnect/remove a device. When I remove a device now it suggests that I lost the device. It still shows up in the list, but without the "Remove" button.