# how to unlink google account from oneplus two without access to the phone

Tags: oneplus-one

I just have sold oneplus 2, unfortunately I have used my email account on it. before sale I have wiped all the data and formatted device through recovery but I just got a call from a buyer that my account is still linked to the phone and he cannot use it. is there any way to unlink it without meeting him? 
I dont want to send him my pass/one time code.

regards

Answer (score 1):

it's like explained [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/87842/remove-my-google-account-on-other-peoples-device)

> Go to [Google's security manager page](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1), find the phone you logged in on and click "deauthorize".