# Remove Google Account from a lost phone

Tags: google-play-store, gmail

Is there any way to remove a device from google play without having the phone ? I've lost my phone a while ago and i can't log in into Google Play from a new phone without removing it from the lost phone. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove my Google account on other people's device](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/87842/remove-my-google-account-on-other-peoples-device)

Comment: I've searched a lot but i forgot to mention that i don't have a "remove device" button or anything like this, so that's the problem. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Change your password, if somebody tries to use the account it will ask you to enter the new password. You can also try: https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager

That's for security. As for not being able to login on the new phone, that sounds very fishy, so I would contact Google, or the manufacturer of your new phone.