# How to remove my Gmail account from Android 5.1?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I added and logged in my Gmail account on my friend's Android (Lollipop 5.1) phone Lenovo A 6000 or 7000. Now I am unable to remove my account from his device. Help me please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove my Google account on other people's device](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/87842/remove-my-google-account-on-other-peoples-device)

Answer (score 2):

Simply go under **Settings** > **Account and app syncing**, select your Gmail account and click **Delete account or services**.