# How do I deactivate my Google account on my father's phone

Tags: contacts, google-account

I logged into my Google account with my father's mobile. Now all my contacts have synced with his contact list. How do I deactivate my account on his phone?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Quick hint for a new member: We've got tags for specific topics, and those often have a tag-wiki associated, containing first-aid and hints. In your case, it's the [google-account tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-account/info) which would guide you into the right direction, namely: [Remove my Google account on other people's device](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/87842/16575). Does that fit your needs?

Answer (score 2):

You can also revoke all your account access remotely. For that log in to your google account and go to account settings. [This](https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity) is the link for online review your activity on devices.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to below path:

**If you have multiple accounts:**

Settings >> Accounts >> Click on Google >> Select account to deactivate >> Select overflow dropdown & click on Remove account.

**If you have 1 account:**

Settings >> Accounts >> Click on Google >> Select overflow dropdown & click on Remove account.

[image: Click on the remove account]

<sub>Click image for larger version</sub>